# Guest acount as part of group X

Tags: permissions, login, guest-session, groups

I have a class where kids login using guest account.
I did customize this account by following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) instructions.

Now my question is how can I set user groups, so that the guest account is a part of a group?

For example: For programming Arduono or running iTalc client, user has to be part of a specific group, but using guest login generates every time new user "guest-SomeRandNumber"